# Read a same property of all the members of an heterogeneous collection, in scala?

Tags: scala, slick

Consider that we have a collection of objects, all of them being case classes, and that all of them have a field, say a uuid, that we want to collect for further use. In my particular case, the objects are coming as rows from four different database tables. In other cases, they could just come from some heterogeneous container, or streamed from a pipe, or whatever.

Using a mix of introspection from java I can read all the uuids in a single stroke, as

```
val LocalTables=Seq(t1,t2,t3,t4)
for (t <- LocalTables) {
 t foreach ( v => {
  val metodo=v.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("id")
  println(metodo.invoke(v))
  }
}
```

But I feel dirty. Is there some way to tell scala to go and access v.id straighforwardly?

This concrete use case is for database access, so it can be trivially solved with a particular query. But the problem is more general and I want to understand what tools can be used to run a *foreach* over some collection of heterogeneous values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various options that trade off between precision/safety and simplicity/flexibility. A lot of the [logic for Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections) applies. Options that come to mind are:

### Structural types

Very easy to use and more-or-less safe, even if they end up compiling to reflection:

```
val localTables = Seq[{def id: UUID}](t1, t2, t3, t4)
localTables foreach {t => println(t.id)}
```

### A trait

Very safe, but requires you to modify your types:

```
trait HasId { def id: UUID }
case class Something(id: UUID, ...) extends HasId
val localTables = Seq[HasId](...)
...
```

### Shapeless `HList` and `poly`

Safe and flexible, but a bit more intimidating

```
import shapeless._, hlist._, poly._
object extractId extends Poly1 {
  implicit val caseFoo = at[Foo](_.id)
  implicit val caseBar = at[Bar](_.id)
  ...
}
val localTables = t1 :: t2 :: ... :: HNil // of type Foo :: Bar :: ... :: HNil
val ids: List[UUID] = localTables map extractId toList
ids foreach println
```

Comment: Fine! Now I see it, I can also apply the structural type as `t.asInstanceOf[{def id:UUID}].id`

Comment: That's substantially less safe; you're blindly casting and assuming the `id` is there, whereas if you do it at the `Seq` stage then the compiler will check that the field exists.

Comment: I see. And what about producing a type that somehow is the intersection of the types of t1, t2, t3? Is such thing a usual pattern in scala?

Comment: No; using structural types at all is not really idiomatic scala; type hierarchies are generally expected to be static and explicit, if t1, t2 and t3 have something in common then this commonality should be expressed by the programmer as a trait. If you're adapting some foreign types to use in a common way, the typeclass pattern is the idiomatic way to do that. The idea of treating two types as being somehow related just because they happen to have members with the same field names is not really the scala way.